# Is it possible to configure the default folder of the "Save as" -dialogue in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-management, default-settings

Caveat: A user who knew DOS inside out, but has lost touch since.

> Is it possible to configure the "Save As"-dialogue in Windows 10 in such a way that the default folder (=the folder whose contents are displayed in the pane) would be "the current folder"? That is, the folder where I started the program from?

This behavior of windows 10 has been getting on my nerves. I have a file in folder X associated with program Y. So I open X, and click the icon of the file. Then I modify the file, and want to save another copy of it with the "Save As"-function from within that program (or [in the case of Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224685/1155) I want to some output within that program). I find it very annoying that the folder X is not the default one opened in that pane. Instead, the contents of the folder only relevant to some earlier operation are displayed in that pane.

I may be using my laptop in some archaic way, but with nearly everything else configurable, why isn't this? Or is it? AFAICT the default folder displayed in that pane is chosen according to the previous "Save As" operation, when, in my humble opinion, the folder of the previous "Open"  operation would be a more logical choice.

Over time I have misplaced several files as a consequence of this. I know, I should just learn to check, but often forget, because this save as -operation is just a small step in my overall work flow.

In [this closely related question](https://superuser.com/q/1218424/604579) the answerers deal with Windows 7 and specific Microsoft software.  I may be misinformed in thinking that the way this is done is that Windows 10 gives the same "Save As" -dialogue to all the programs. But, if that is the case then a solution to my "current problem" with Wolfram Mathematica could also solve the exact same problem I face the next time I use a component of MS Office.

The reason I suspect this behavior is governed by Windows 10 as opposed to the individual programs is that I asked about this in a [Wolfram technical support forum](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2014925). No definite replies from developers there yet, but other users raised the suspicion that this a "feature" of the OS.

Comment: "The reason I suspect this behaviour is governed by Windows 10 as opposed to the individual programs" It's both. Some (not all) programs will customise the way "Save As" is handled, either by providing a completely new dialog (rare) or by hooks into the standard dialog that change it's behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill. In line with your description it turned out that it **is** possible to control this within Mathematica. I got instructions to do that at the linked Wolfram forum. Leaving this question here for a little while in case somebody can say something about configuring Windows's behavior here. Of course, if nothing can be said about that, it may be best to simply delete this question?